# C++11 return a std::array with different sizes

Tags: templates, c++11, stdarray

I'd like to create such a structure:

```
struct Arrays{
    typedef unsigned char byte_t;

    std::array<byte_t, X>& get(int x, int y)
    {
        switch(x){
            case 1: return arr_1.at(y);
            case 2: return arr_2.at(y);
            ... up to ...
            case 50: return arr_50.at(y);
            default: break;
        }
    }

    std::vector<std::array<byte_t, 1>> arr_1;
    std::vector<std::array<byte_t, 2>> arr_2;
    ... up to ....
    std::vector<std::array<byte_t, 50>> arr_50;
};
```

I know that

```
std::array<byte_t, 1>
```

and

```
std::array<byte_t, 2>
```

are different structures, so this is impossible in this way. How can I managed with it in different manner? Do I have to return `byte_t*` from the method?

Comment: erm, return a `std::vector<>`?

Comment: I forgot about an &. I have to have an ability to modify this array.

Comment: you can return a reference to the vector, and modify it to your hearts content...

Comment: Yes. But as far as I understand, you suggest to create a copy of an std::array inside a std::vector and return a vector. The oryginal data cannot be modified in this way.

Comment: No, instead of using `std::array<>` in your `arr_1` et al, use a `std::vector<>`, e.g. `std::vector<std::vector<byte_t>> arr_1;` then return a reference to this..

Comment: It is definitely not an option due to a huge memory overhead.

Comment: what "huge memory overhead"? A vector object (IIRC in gcc is 24 bytes), this will be in addition to the size of the content (which should be the same as that of your arrays), so the overhead for using vector is 24 * 50 * N where N is the depth of each member you have, btw - using a switch is not very smart here, as you can simply declare a three dimensional vector here! `std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<byte_t>>> _data`, then your function becomes, `return _data[x][y];` (you'll have to check that both `x`/`y` exist...

Comment: Yes and every nested vector takes an additional 3*word size. So inside a std::vector<byte_t> I will store for example 3 bytes of data (equivalent for std::array<byte_t, 3>) and have an additional 24bytes for a vector structure.

Comment: Okay, so are you running this on some embedded system where this overhead is a concern? If so, then the the best option here is to return this, `std::pair<byte_t*, byte_t*>`, you should be able to figure out what goes there... Else, stick to what makes your code the easiest to read/understand...

Comment: No it is not an embeded system. But in a complex structure like vector<vector<byte_t>> when the outer vector contains 1M elements it is visible overhead. The pair of pointers seems interesting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the previous comments have said, the array size is a compile-time constant. The only way to achieve this then is to pass `x` as a template argument. How about the following? (For convenience, I have defined a class `vector_of_arrays` to hold your vectors `arr_1` to `arr_50` in such a way that I can refer to each one by the number rather than having to switch and give a name)

```
#include <array>
#include <type_traits>
#include <vector>

template <typename type, size_t max_size>
class vector_of_arrays : public std::vector<std::array<type, max_size>>
{
private:
    vector_of_arrays<type, max_size - 1> _next;

public:
    template <size_t size>
    typename std::enable_if<(size < max_size), vector_of_arrays<type, size>&>::type
    get_vector_for_size()
    {
        return _next.get_vector_for_size<size>();
    }

    template <size_t size>
    typename std::enable_if<(size == max_size), vector_of_arrays<type, size>&>::type
    get_vector_for_size()
    {
        return *this;
    }
};

template <typename type>
class vector_of_arrays<type, 1> : public std::vector<std::array<type, 1>>
{
public:
    template <size_t size>
    typename std::enable_if<(size == 1), vector_of_arrays<type, size>&>::type
    get_vector_for_size()
    {
        return *this;
    }
};

struct arrays
{
    typedef unsigned char byte_t;
    vector_of_arrays<byte_t, 50> va;

    template <size_t x>
    std::array<byte_t, x>& emplace_array()
    {
        va.get_vector_for_size<x>().emplace_back();
        return *(va.get_vector_for_size<x>().end() - 1);
    }

    template <size_t x>
    std::array<byte_t, x>& get(int y)
    {
        return va.get_vector_for_size<x>().at(y);
    }
};
```

To test this code, you could do something like

```
arrays foo;
auto& arr1 = foo.emplace_array<3>();
arr1[0] = 1.;
arr1[1] = 2.;
arr1[2] = 3.;

auto& arr2 = foo.get<3>(0);
std::cout << arr2[0] << ' ' << arr2[1] << ' ' << arr2[2] << std::endl;
```

Comment: The OP has compile time constants -- `1` through `50`, in the `switch`/`case` statement.  The issue isn't the lack of compile time constants in general, but compile time constants *outside the body of the function*.

Comment: Sure, but I sort of interpreted the original post to mean that the parameter `x` can be expected to be a compile-time constant wherever the function is called.

Answer (score 1):

First, you are violating DRY.

Replace this:

```
std::vector<std::array<byte_t, 1>> arr_1;
std::vector<std::array<byte_t, 2>> arr_2;
... up to ....
std::vector<std::array<byte_t, 50>> arr_50;
```

with something like:

```
template<typename Pack, unsigned X> struct append;
template<template<unsigned...>class Pack, unsigned... Xs, unsigned X>
struct append<Pack<Xs...>, X> {
  typedef Pack<Xs..., X> type;
};
template<typename Pack, unsigned X> using Append=typename append<Pack,X>::type;


template<unsigned N, template<unsigned>class Contents>
struct auto_tuple {
  typedef Append< typename auto_tuple<N-1, Contents>::type, Contents<N-1> > type;
};
template<template<unsigned>class Contents>
struct auto_tuple<0, Contents> {
  typedef std::tuple<> type;
};
template<unsigned N, template<unsigned>class Contents>
using AutoTuple = typename auto_tuple<N,Contents>::type;
```

where `AutoTuple<N, Contents>` applies `0` through `N-1` to `Contents` and generates a `std::tuple` out of it.  Write:

```
template<typename T, unsigned N>
using vec_of_array = std::vector<std::array<T, N>>;
template<unsigned N>
using vec_of_byte_array = vec_of_array<byte_t, N>;
template<unsigned N>
using get_nth_byte_array = vec_of_byte_array<N+1>;
```

which you use to populate your `tuple` like:

```
typedef AutoTuple<50, get_nth_byte_array> my_tuple;
```

which is a `std::tuple` of `50` different `std::vector`s, each of which store a `std::array` of `1` through `50` `byte`s.

This took far fewer than `50` lines, and while this will be harder to get it to work and understand it, it means that the code is uniform and generated once: there is far less of a chance that one particular line is wrong, and a far higher chance that everything is wrong at once.  And you can use a compile-time value to extract the nth element via `std::get<7>(my_tuple)`.  Oh, and if you want `100` or `10` instead of `50`?  Change one constant.

Next, a `contiguous_range` structure that is basically a dressed up pair of pointers gives you a type-erased way to look at an array (or other buffer) of `N` elements, like [Passing a std::array of unknown size to a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17156282/passing-a-stdarray-of-unknown-size-to-a-function/17156692#17156692)

Now, you can either write your big switch statement manually, or you can build a table of function pointers that extract the `contiguous_range` and build it automatically.

```
// DataStorage is the tuple of std::vector of std::array
template<unsigned...> struct seq{};
template<unsigned max, unsigned... s> struct make_seq:make_seq<max-1, max-1, s...> {};
template<unsigned... s> struct make_seq<0,s...>:seq<s...> {};

template<unsigned N>
struct get_array {
  static contig_range<byte> get(DataStorage& data, unsinged idx) {
    return ( std::get<N>( std::forward<Data>(data) )[idx];
  }
};
```

and build an array of 50 of them (each with a different `N`) stored in an array of:

```
typedef contig_range<byte> (*array_getter)( DataStorage&, unsigned idx );
template<unsigned N, unsigned... S>
std::array< array_getter, N > populate_array_helper( seq<S...> ) {
  return { get_array<S>::get... };
}
template<unsigned N>
std::array< array_getter, N > populate_array() {
  return populate_array_helper( make_seq<N>() );
}
```

which you can then use the run-time argument to lookup, call it, and you get a type-erased instance of your contiguous array of `byte`.

Non-code overhead is 50 pointers (for the lookup table), 3 pointers (for the containing vector).

And you never do a cpoy/paste of the same code 50 times over with a single number changed each time, one of which has a slight typo in it that generates a subtle fenceposting bug that only occurs in one obscure, hard to reproduce test case in release mode only.