# How do I Pass an array object (Class Template c++) to a function as a parameter?

Tags: c++, arrays

If I declare an array (using c++ Class Template) like this,

```
#include <array> //standard c++ library
 int main()
{
 array<int,3> myarray{10,20,30}; 
}
```

How will I be able to send this array object to a function as a parameter.

If I pass like this it works :

```
void f_print(array<int, 3> object){}
int main()
{
 array<int, 3> myarray{10,20,30};
 f_print(myarray);
}
```

but the problem here is I am hard coding the size in the function. The whole point to work like this to use array as an object type so I can use array.size().
So How can I pass this array type object (c++ Class Template) without hardcoding the size.

Edit_1: Why can't I send the array object as only an object where I use all the properties of the object inside the function parameter.

Comment: related/dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17156282/passing-a-stdarray-of-unknown-size-to-a-function.  Not the biggest fan of the answers though.

Comment: Why can't I send the array object as only an object. That's actually my query.

Answer (score 5):

You can template either the array type

```
template<typename T>
void f_print(std::array<T, 3> const& object);
```

Or the size

```
template<size_t S>
void f_print(std::array<int, S> const& object);
```

Or both:

```
template<typename T, size_t S>
void f_print(std::array<T, S> const& object);
```

The compiler should be able to deduce the correct template arguments in all the cases.

Comment: I think option D: template the parameter to accept a container:
`template<class T> void f_print const T& object);`
would also fit OP's needs

Comment: Why can't I send the array object as only an object. That's actually my query

Answer (score 4):

Make the function a template to avoid hard coding it for the size:

```
template<size_t S>
void f_print(array<int, S> object){}
```

See a [**Live Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cdd16761f1d1c19e).

Comment: Why can't I send the array object as only an object. That's actually my query

Comment: @JabedHossain Because each of the template parameter combinations of `std::array` forms it's own class. These aren't really related and cannot be deduced to _the_ array object. Also if that is your real question, why don't you put that in your question post?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing the point of arrays. It's in the very nature of an array that its **size belongs to its type**. That's the case for raw arrays and it's the case for `std::array` as well. Hard-coding the size 3 of `std::array<int, 3>` in the function is as unavoidable as hard-coding the `int`.

In fact, in my experience, the best way to *think* about an array like for example `int[4]` or `std::array<int, 4>` is as a shorthand for `int a, b, c, d`.

I'd say a **template** only circumvents the issue in a very superficial way. If you create a template with a size parameter, then you only end up with a lot of different functions for different array types. `std::array<int, 3>`, `std::array<int, 4>`, `std::array<int, 5>` and so on all result in different template instantiations. It's in the same way as you end up with different template instantiations for `std::array<int, 3>`, `std::array<double, 3>` and `std::array<std::string, 3>`.

Mind that turning the size into a template parameter may still be the solution you are *actually* looking for. If, however, you need a container for which the size is not known at compile time, then use `std::vector`.

Comment: I knew I could use std::vector but I wanted to know as I am declaring class type object array why the array doesn't behave like an object while its being used as a function parameter. But thanks for the answer. Learned from it .