# How to pass an std::array with unknown size? in C++

Tags: c++, arrays

I'd like to pass an C++ std::array defined as

```
array<int,100> arrayName
```

to another function, but I don't want to specify there the size, so I can easily change the size only at creation of the array.

How do I write this? I can't write

```
function(array<> arrayName)
```

as I would do with an char array...

Kind regards, iova.

Comment: Do you want to be able to set the size at runtime or compile time?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing a std::array of unknown size to a function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17156282/17034)

Comment: At compile time would be ok. At runtime I think it's not possible with an array, or?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you know the array size in compile-time, as is implied by your usage of `std::array`, then you have *templates* to the rescue. To restrictively support `std::array`s of `int` of different sizes you can do this:

```
#include <array>

template <size_t N>
void ArrayFunc(std::array<int, N> arr)
{
    // Do something with `arr`
}

int main()
{
    std::array<int, 10> arr10;
    std::array<int, 20> arr20;

    ArrayFunc(arr10);
    ArrayFunc(arr20);

    return 0;
}
```

Note the passing *by value* of the `arr` parameter of `ArrayFunc()`, a thing you should consider whether it is desired or not -- I was just following your example (in pseudo) in your question. If you don't really want to copy the entire `std::array` for each function call then you can do either:

```
template <size_t N>
void ArrayFunc(std::array<int, N>& arr)
```

or

```
template <size_t N>
void ArrayFunc(const std::array<int, N>& arr)
```

Depending on whether you will be modifying `arr` in the function or not.

Answer (score 0):

Use of vector will be good choice as it dynamic in nature but be carefull as it consume more space it gets double after initial value like if vector u declare of 10 after 10 it will GET 20 after 20 get 30 every it will grow by 10 .  And still u dont want u use it u can create your own  dynamic array  by using  two array and using some pointer .