# Match the size of std::array with parameter pack

Tags: c++

I have a function which can match `std::vector` and other containers well:

```cpp
template <typename T, typename... Rest,
          template <typename, typename...> class Container>
std::string DoSomethingOnContainer(Container<T, Rest...> vals) {
  // do something
}
```

But it cannot match `std::array`, e.g. `std::array<int, 10>`. How to make the function also match  `std::array`?

I am using c++17.

Comment: This should do it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17156282/passing-a-stdarray-of-unknown-size-to-a-function

Comment: On naive idea: Can we use "template <typename C> std::string DoSomethingOnContainer(C vals) { ... }" in your case? Or can we make a specialized method specific for `std::array`?

Comment: Remeber C++ templates are expanded at compiler time.

Comment: Reason matching fails is in `std::array<Type T, size_t val>` the second parameter is **not** type but a value(like 1, 2, 3 etc.). Create a different overload for `std::array` maybe? or something like @ZhaoYunjian mentioned.

Comment: this is a fundamental limitation of C++ templates. `auto…` or something like that (i don’t remember) was proposed in order to cover this case. most likely i would go with another overload or not use template templates at all and rely of afinae (e.g. mention Container::iterator) or concepts.

Comment: `template <typename  Container> std::string DoSomethingOnContainer(Container vals) { using T = typename Container::value_type; /* do something */ }` might be a good alternative.