# const and typedef of arrays in C

Tags: c, arrays, constants, typedef

In C, it's possible to `typedef` an array, using this construction :

`typedef int table_t[N];`

Here, `table_t` is now defined as an array of N `int`. Any variable declared such as `table_t t;` will now behave as a normal array of `int`.

The point of such construction is to be used as an argument type in a function, such as :

`int doSomething(table_t t);`

A relatively equivalent function prototype could have been :

`int doSomething(int* t);`

The merit of the first construction is that it enforces `N` as the size of the table. In many circumstances, it's safer to enforce this property, rather than relying on the programmer to properly figure out this condition.

Now it's all good, except that, in order to guarantee that the content of table will not be modified, it's necessary to use the `const` qualifier.

The following statement is relatively simple to understand :

`int doSomething(const int* t);`

Now, `doSomething` guarantee that it will not modify the content of the table passed as a pointer.
Now, what about this almost equivalent construction ? :

`int doSomething(const table_t t);`

What is `const` here ? the content of the table, or the pointer to the table ?
If it's the pointer which is `const`, is there another way (C90 compatible) to retain the ability to define the size of the table and to tell that its content will be const ?

Note that it's also necessary sometimes to modify the content of the table, so the `const` property cannot be embedded into the typedef definition.

[*Edit*] Thanks for the excellent answers received so far.
To summarize :

- The initial assumption of typedef enforcing size *N* was completely wrong. It basically behaves the same as a normal pointer.
- The `const` property will also behave the same as if it was a pointer *(in stark contrast with a typedef to a pointer type, as underlined by @random below)*
- To enforce a size (which was not the initial question, but end up being quite important now...), see [Jonathan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4710472/333698)

Comment: It doesn't matter if you declare the argument as an array of `N` entries, it will still be a pointer, and the size `N` is discarded.

Comment: If I understood your supposition of "enforces N as the table size", its wrong. [See counter-example](http://ideone.com/p5KP0N). No such enforcement takes place.

Comment: [Contents are constant](http://ideone.com/vUPzYf)

Comment: *"..Any variable declared such as table_t t; will now behave as a normal array"*... integer array to be specific.

Comment: You might find [Write the prototype for a C function that takes an array of exactly 16 integers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4710454/) informative.

Comment: "The point of such construction is to be used as an argument type in a function" - no it isn't , you gain nothing by using it as function argument type.

Comment: Thanks for the link @Jonathan, it's an excellent complementary answer.

Comment: "Hence the const property will behave the same" - it's still an array type. For example, `sizeof(table_t)` is `N*sizeof(int)`, not `sizeof(int *)`. Arrays evaluate to pointers in many contexts, but they're not actually pointers.

Comment: As it happens, const does _not_ act the same. It acts _kind of_ the same as `const int *`, but if the type had been `typedef int *table_t`, then `const table_t` would have acted instead like `int * const`, which is very different.

Comment: @random, this would be in contradiction with Jens Gunstedt statement

Comment: @Chan Not really. `int const *` is the same as `const int *`, and different from `int * const`. The last one makes the pointer type constant. The statement I was replying to was incorrectly suggesting that table_t was actually a pointer type, and that the results are the same as it would be for const pointer_t (with pointer_t defined as in my answer below).

Comment: > For example, sizeof(table_t) is N*sizeof(int), not sizeof(int *).

In the context of `int doSomething(table_t t);`, how would evaluate `sizeof(t)` then ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The content of the table will be constant. Easily checked with this code.

```
#include<stdio.h>

typedef int table_t[3];
void doSomething(const table_t t)
{
    t++;    //No error, it's a non-const pointer.
    t[1]=3; //Error, it's a pointer to const.

}

int main()
{
    table_t t={1,2,3};
    printf("%d %d %d %ld",t[0],t[1],t[2],sizeof(t));
    t[1]=5;
    doSomething(t);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Function parameters and plain local arrays are not the same thing.

Comment: @Lundin: I've edited the code. Is it right now? or am I still not understanding?

Comment: Yes it is correct now, although you don't explain why it behaves that way.

Answer (score 13):

First, you are mistaken, the function prototypes

```
int doSomething(table_t t);
int doSomething(int* t);
```

are exactly equivalent. For function parameters, the first array dimension is always rewritten as a pointer. So there is no guarantee for the size of the array that is received.

`const`-qualification on arrays always applies to the base type of the array, so the two declarations

```
const table_t a;
int const a[N];
```

are equivalent, and for functions parameters we have

```
int doSomething(const table_t t);
int doSomething(int const* t);
```

Answer (score 5):

Array types and pointer types are not 100% equivalent, even in this context where you do ultimately get *a* pointer type for the function parameter. Your mistake is in assuming that `const` would have acted the same way if it *were* a pointer type.

To expand on ARBY's example:

```
typedef int table_t[3];
typedef int *pointer_t;

void doSomething(const table_t t)
{
    t++;    //No error, it's a non-const pointer.
    t[1]=3; //Error, it's a pointer to const.
}

void doSomethingElse(const pointer_t t)
{
    t++;    //Error, it's a const pointer.
    t[1]=3; //No error, it's pointer to plain int
}
```

It does act similarly to `const int *`, but `const pointer_t` is instead equivalent to `int * const`.

(Also, disclaimer, user-defined names ending with _t are not allowed by POSIX, they're reserved for future expansion)

Comment: That's a good point. The initial question was limited to `typedef int table_t[N];` example (hence the first one).  That's nonetheless interesting to underline the difference with `typedef int *pointer_t;`.

Answer (score 4):

> The merit of the first construction is that it enforces N as the size of the table.

I'm not sure what you mean here. In what contexts would it "enforce" it? If you declare a function as

```
int doSomething(table_t t);
```

array size will *not* be enforced. I order to enforce the size, you'd have to go a different route

```
int doSomething(table_t *t); // equivalent to 'int (*t)[N]'
```

> What is const here ?

As for `const`... When `const` is applied to array type it "drops down" all the way to array elements. This means that `const table_t` is an array of constant `int`s, i.e. it is equivalent to `const int [N]` type. The end result of this is that the array becomes non-modifiable. In function parameter declaration context `const table_t` will be converted into `const int *`.

However, note one peculiar detail that is not immediately obvious in this case: the array type itself remains non-const-qualified. It is the *individual elements* that become `const`. In fact, it is impossible to const-qualify the array type itself in C. Any attempts to do so will make const-qualification to "sift down" to individual elements.

This peculiarity leads to rather unpleasant consequences in array const-correctness. For example, this code will not compile in C

```
table_t t;
const table_t *pt = &t;
```

even though it looks quite innocently from the const-correctness point of view and will compile for any non-array object type. C++ language updated its const-correctness rules to resolve this issue, while C continues to stick to its old ways.

Answer (score 3):

The standard 6.7.6.3 says:

> A declaration of a parameter as ‘‘array of type’’ shall be adjusted to ‘‘qualified pointer to type’’

Meaning that when you declare a function parameter as a `const int` array type, it decays into a pointer to `const int` (first element in array). Equivalent to `const int*` in this case.

Also note that because of the above mentioned rule, the array size specified adds no additional type safety! This is one big flaw in the C language, but that's how it is.

Still, it is good practice to declare the array with fixed width like you have, because static analysers or clever compilers may produce a diagnostic about different types.

Comment: Good point. Static analyzers tend to be much more complete at finding overflow errors nowadays. An indication of size can indeed hint them.